# Backgroundtask.js - how to include other files

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I've started playing with time triggers, and defined my task in bacvkgroundtask.js. Now I have an simple, maybe silly question:

- How should I include external files?

Usually we do this in the html file, but in this case, the entry point for the task is just one javascript file.

Edit: Here's a link to msdn sample creating the backgroundtask.js file that I need to "import" other files into. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977045.aspx

Thanks

Larsi

Comment: question is not clear. you can add backgroundtask.js in the html file as script and expose utility methods using [WinJS.Namespace.define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212667.aspx) if that is what you were looking for. Utility methods can then be invoked from page.ready or other event handler.

Comment: @Sushil Thanks for the link. But my problem was that the WinJS was undefined. I found this link: Is this the way to go: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/368aa3c1-e027-4855-8c80-b57156dd1fd4/ ?